# jQuery: How can I reliably fire a plugin after loading AJAX content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a Slideshow plugin called [Slides](http://slidesjs.com/) to load a slideshow in an element after it is loaded via a jQuery AJAX request. After much wrangling, the plugin fires, but looking at the Inspector, it looks like the plugin is being fired for every image in the slideshow because the plugin in generating way too many navigational elements.

```
$('a').click(function(){    
    var location = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
    $(this).find('a').removeAttr('href');           
    $("section").animate({height: 0, opacity: 0}, 500, "swing", function (){
        $(this).css('height','auto').load(location + " .container", function(){
            $('section').find('img').load(function(){
                $('#slides').slides();
                var newHeight = $('section').height();
                $('section').animate({height: newHeight, opacity: 1}, 500, "swing");
            })
        })              
    })
})
```

I realize SE is not Slides.js support, but I have this feeling that I'm just not using jQuery correctly in this case.

Comment: _"but then just breaks."_ That's not too much informative...

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I couldn't think of a coherent way to say "shows nothing, then randomly shows a an image, then nothing for 10 more click, then an image again." I've updated the question with a little more info, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but I'm under no illusion that it's a proper answer:

You're looking for all anchor tags with `$('a')` and then looking inside of them for additional anchor tags with `.find('a')`, and then removing their href value. I don't understand what ANY of that is meant to accomplish. All that beginning "set up" stage is doing is taking something like this:

```
<a href="/something">Click me</a> <!-- this is the one listening for the click -->
  <a href="/somethingElse">A link</a>
</a>
```

and turning it into this:

```
<a href="/something">Click me</a>
  <a>A link</a>
</a>
```

Anchor tags are not valid without an href, but most browsers should forgive you. But I just don't understand why do this? And why listen with the wrapping anchor instead of the internal anchor? And why have an anchor wrapping an anchor at all?

Certainly seeing the markup will be useful.